# Ubuntu Splash Screen Customization

Tags: package-management, customization, plymouth

I wanted to know how to customize the splash screen in Ubuntu 13. I have tried to install Plymouth Manager but when I run sudo apt-get update it says it was unable to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages. I opened the address in Firefox but it didn't open. Also I would like to know where the files for the Ubuntu Logo, Splash Screen Background, etc. are located (to customize them). In previous versions they were located at usr/share/images. I am running Ubuntu 13 Raring Ringtail on VMWare Player. The host is an Acer 5600U running Windows 8. Thnx.

Comment: Which 13 version do you use? 13.04 or 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for Plymouth files in "**/lib/plymouth/themes**". 
Also you can search themes in repositories. Write in terminal this

```
apt-cache search plymouth-theme-
```

Comment: Thnx. How do I add the themes to the folder Should I put them directly in or in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: [Choosing a GRUB 2 Background Image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#Choosing_a_GRUB_2_Background_Image)

After finished the installation, the splash images' in the folder /boot/grub. You can copy the images you like into the folder, keep note the priority of the images as the link: [Image Priority](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#Image_Priority)
Do remember to update grub after every changing splash images: sudo update-grub

Plymouth, Ubuntu logo you can find out: /lib/plymouth/themes. This link's also help for Plymouth knowledge: [Get your precious Plymouth splash screen back!](http://cristalinux.blogspot.com/2011/01/get-your-precious-plymouth-splash.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Plymouth Manager on Ubuntu 13.04, but the PPA isn't working. You have to download the .deb file and install it.

Check the Plymouth Manager site/blog here: http://plymouthmanager.wordpress.com/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.